# RavenDB Query on Datetime with value in collection offset

Tags: datetime, ravendb

I am trying to query RavenDB on a Datetime which is being offset by a entry in a collection.  As shown below, I have an AppointmentReminder object which contains many AppointmentReminderJobs.  I'd like to query for AppointmentReminders where the AppointmentReminderJob is due to run.

My models are as follows:

```
public class AppointmentReminder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public ReminderStatus ReminderStatus { get; set; }
    public List<AppointmentReminderJob> AppointmentReminderJobs { get; set; }
 }

public class AppointmentReminderJob
{
    public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
    public int DaysPrior { get; set; }
}
```

My controller and attempt to retrieve a list of AppointmentReminders which have current jobs to run (I know this Where clause isn't complete, but I've tried to simplify it with no luck):

```
public ActionResult GetJobsQueuedListCurrent()
    {
        var jobsqueuedlist = RavenSession.Query<AppointmentReminder>()
            .Where(appointmentreminder => appointmentreminder.AppointmentReminderJobs.Any(x => appointmentreminder.AppointmentDateTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(x.DaysPrior)))
            .OrderBy(appointmentreminder => appointmentreminder.AppointmentDateTime)
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();

        return View("List", jobsqueuedlist);

    }
```

Calling the above yields a response of:

```
variable 'x' of type 'ProjectName.Models.AppointmentReminderJob' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

I am trying to set up an index like so:

```
public class JobsQueuedListCurrent : AbstractIndexCreationTask<AppointmentReminder, JobsQueuedListCurrent.IndexResult>
{
    public class IndexResult
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime JobDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public JobsQueuedListCurrent()
    {


        Map = appointmentreminders => from appointmentreminder in appointmentreminders
                                      from job in appointmentreminder.AppointmentReminderJobs
                                      select new 
                                      { 
                                          Id = appointmentreminder.Id, 
                                          JobDateTime = appointmentreminder.AppointmentDateTime.AddDays(job.DaysPrior)
                                      };
        Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.JobDateTime, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm querying and getting expected results using:

```
var jobsqueuedlist = RavenSession.Query<JobsQueuedListCurrent.IndexResult, JobsQueuedListCurrent>()
            .Where(x=>x.JobDateTime >= DateTime.Now)
            .As<AppointmentReminder>()
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();

        return View("List", jobsqueuedlist);
```

My last question regarding this would be, my map/index can definitely result in multiple entries of the same document id (appointmentreminder), but my resulting list contains only 1 instance of the document.  I'm happy with the way that works, I'm just not sure if I should be performing a reduce or doing something else in my code or just let Raven handle it like it seems like it is doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create such a query. This would require RavenDB to perform computation during query, and that is not allowed.
RavenDB only allows queries on the data in the index.

What you *can* do it setup the computation in the index, and then query on *that*.

Comment: Thanks!  You got me pointed in the right direction.  I've edited my question above with the code that got me working.  I added a question about best practices, I wasn't expecting that Raven would only return 1 instance of my document even though my index had multiple entries that matched the where clause all pointing to the same document.  I'm not sure if I should be doing anything else to help or just let Raven continue to handle knowing just to return one instance of each document.