# RavenHQ index query returning (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

My original question can be found here:
[RavenDB Index Query Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166439/ravendb-query-on-datetime-with-value-in-collection-offset)

I got that working great using the following index now:

```
public class JobsQueuedListCurrent : AbstractIndexCreationTask<AppointmentReminder, JobsQueuedListCurrent.IndexResult>
{
    public class IndexResult
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
        public ReminderStatus ReminderStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime JobDateTime { get; set; }
        public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public JobsQueuedListCurrent()
    {


        Map = appointmentreminders => from appointmentreminder in appointmentreminders
                                      from job in appointmentreminder.NotificationJobs
                                      where (appointmentreminder.ReminderStatus != ReminderStatus.Confirmed)

                                      select new 
                                      { 
                                          Id = appointmentreminder.Id, 
                                          AppointmentDateTime = appointmentreminder.AppointmentDateTime,
                                          ReminderStatus = appointmentreminder.ReminderStatus,
                                          JobDateTime = appointmentreminder.AppointmentDateTime.AddDays(job.DaysOffset),
                                          JobStatus = job.JobStatus
                                      };

        Store(x => x.AppointmentDateTime, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.ReminderStatus, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.JobDateTime, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.JobStatus, FieldStorage.Yes);

    }
}
```

I moved my code from my local machine to AppHarbor and RavenHQ.  I can connect and query normal data in Appharbor and RavenHQ now.  My controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetJobsQueuedListCurrent()
    {
        var jobsqueuedlist = RavenSession.Query<JobsQueuedListCurrent.IndexResult, JobsQueuedListCurrent>()
            .OrderBy(x => x.AppointmentDateTime)
            .As<AppointmentReminder>()
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();

        return View("List", jobsqueuedlist);

    }
```

That works fine, when I add the following where clause:

```
.Where(x => (x.JobDateTime <= DateTime.Now))
```

So that the controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetJobsQueuedListCurrent()
    {
        var jobsqueuedlist = RavenSession.Query<JobsQueuedListCurrent.IndexResult, JobsQueuedListCurrent>()
            .Where(x => (x.JobDateTime <= DateTime.Now))
            .OrderBy(x => x.AppointmentDateTime)
            .As<AppointmentReminder>()
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();

        return View("List", jobsqueuedlist);

    }
```

This now results in an error (500): Internal Server Error, a link to the pastebin of the output is below:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HXvC15jn)

What can I do to allow the query to use datetime in the Where clause?  BTW I am using the latest unstable on my client (1.2.2139-Unstable) to talk to RavenHQ.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 1.2 client to talk to a 1.0 server.